# What purpose does injecting SVGs serve?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm currently working on a site for a client that is using this library quite a bit to inject SVGs into each page:
https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector

Most pages on this site include 15+ SVG icons used as icons and I'm trying to minimize the number of requests which injecting doesn't remedy.

I'm considering including these SVGs as inline elements to reduce the number of HTTP requests on each page but I don't understand what the purpose of injecting is over just inlining them to start with. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: They seem to be making their argument [here](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector#why).

Comment: Just for the record there is another SVG injector available that is better suited for dynamic pages, because it uses the "onload" attribute to trigger injection: https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using inline SVG is necessary for some reasons the library README mentions:

- Using embedded Javascript
- Being able to style it using CSS

On the other hand, using inline SVG is bad for other [arguable] reasons:

- If you need you use the same SVG twice, you need to include it twice. Generally speaking, repeating code is not good, as it tends to lead to bugs.
- SVG in source files produces bloat. It's much better to separate the SVG source in another file.

The library you mention solves these problems by allowing you to store the SVGs in different files, yet be able to use them inline.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently trying to improve performance of these pages and they, in general, have a lot of requests. These SVGs are used one time per page. Is it worth considering inlining them or would any performance increase be negligible?

Comment: CSV ??. you mean SVG!.

Comment: If your site uses some build system like webpack, I'd consider using a plugin that does the same this library does on runtime but on buildtime, like this one https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader. Also, if you use [application cache](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwji-t_CtuTWAhUDfpAKHbVcCEIQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FUsing_the_application_cache&usg=AOvVaw2944I56oWAVsgEJQfUxO5i), the [possible] performance boost of inlining assets like SVGs and other images dissappears.

Comment: @nicooga SVG has built-in facilities to re-use SVG across a page and/or reference the same SVG content at multiple places with optional specific CSS overrides at the individual places; cf https://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/ . So the reusability argument made in favor of "SVG injection" doesn't hold water IMHO.

Comment: @imhotap that's a nice feature I did not know. I don't think it removes all the duplication issues though. You still have to repeat all the attributes of the root `svg` element.